# How to run SageTeX on Windows?

Tags: python, sage

I want to use Sage in LaTeX, how do I do that running Sagemath 8.0 on Windows? I use the MikTeX distribution.

I followed the instructions from [Sagemath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html#sec-sagetex-install) but they are for linux. I included the `sagetex` package, which generates a `myfile.sage` file but when I start the Sage shell and run `sage myfile.sage` it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.sage.py", line 7, in <module>
    _st_ = sagetex.SageTeXProcessor('myfile')
  File "/opt/sagemath-8.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sagetex.py", line 76, in __init__
    raise VersionError, errstr
sagetex.VersionError: versions of .sty and .py files do not match.
myfile.sagetex.sage was generated by sagetex.sty version "None", but
is being processed by sagetex.py version "2015/08/26 v3.0-92d9f7a".
Please make sure that TeX is using the sagetex.sty
from your current version of Sage; see
http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/sagetex.html.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned by Pedro Jose Moreno Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820127/how-to-run-sagetex-on-windows/55308183?noredirect=1#comment119488201_55308183), a couple of years after this question was asked a new sage arara rule was [written by the TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521688/98850) (and fixed by Pedro) which works on Windows. Complete instructions are then as follows, to compile your LaTeX file using sagetex with one command.

1. Install MiKTeX and Sagemath
2. Make sure the sagetex package is not installed by MiKTeX
3. Find out your SageTeX installation path, for example `C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.2` or `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.2` for a user installation.
4. Compile your LaTeX file with environment variable `TEXINPUTS=C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.2\runtime\opt\sagemath-9.2\local\share\texmf\tex\latex\sagetex;` such that it finds the `sagetex.sty` package. (Verified with the TeXiFy editor.) If that doesn't work, you could of course always copy the `sagetex.sty` package to your working directory.
5. Create an arara rule. You can keep it local as follows (there are much more possibilities, see the arara docs): create a file `araraconfig.yaml` next to your LaTeX file with following content

```
!config
paths:
- .
```

6. Create a file called `sagetex.yaml` with the contents from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520683/arara-sage-a-sagemath-rule-for-arara (change the paths to your installation):

```
!config
# SageTeX-Rule for arara.
#
# Dear Windows-users, please check the paths
# pathToBashExecutive    and    pathToSageStartfile
# due to your Sage-installation!
#
identifier: sagetex
name: SageTeX
authors:
  - TeXnician (Author)
  - cis (Idea)
  - Pedro J (final fix)
arguments: []
commands:
  - name: A SageTeX Rule for arara
    command: >
      @{
          pathToBashExecutive = "C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\SageMath 9.2\\runtime\\bin\\bash";
          pathToSageStartfile = "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/SageMath 9.2/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.2/sage";
          pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder = currentFile().getParent();
          theWindowsCommand = getCommand(pathToBashExecutive, "-l", pathToSageStartfile, "-c", "os.chdir(r'" + pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder + "'); load('" + getBasename(currentFile()) + ".sagetex.sage')");
          return isWindows(theWindowsCommand, getCommand("sage", getBasename(reference) + ".sagetex.sage"));
         }
```

7. Run `arara myfile.tex`

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use sagetex on windows:

Step 1: Install miktex 2.9 64-bit, full install.

Step 2: Install Texniccenter 2.02 64-bit (I think another program like texworks, texmaker, winedt, etc will work).

Step 3: Install Sagemath 8.6 64-bit or better.

Step 4: Sagetex version in miktex is different to sagetex version in Sagemath 8.6. Then you should install in miktex same version of sagetex as you have in Sagemath.

This can be done copying al files in **c:\Program Files\SageMath 8.6\runtime\opt\sagemath-8.6\local\share\texmf\tex\latex\sagetex** into **c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sagetex**

Now using sagetex on windows is possible according this:

1.- Use texniccenter to compile your .tex document. Remember you have to load sagetex package: *\usepackage{sagetex}*

2.- Sagemath installation on windows has 3 shotcurts. You should open **Sagemath 8.6**, not **Sagemath 8.6 Shell** or **Sagemat 8.6 Notebook**. Remember, **Sagemath 8.6**. After that a shell is opened and when we see **sage:**, sagemath is ready.

3.- Navigate to folder where our files are using "cd" command, like *cd documents*. Is important, if your folder's name has spaces placing it between ' ', i.e. *cd 'folder 1'*

4.- When you are into your destination folder, you can see its contents with "ls". There should be your sagetex.sage file. To process the file you have to write **load('file.sagetex.sage')** (file is the name of your .tex file) and the procces will start when you press enter.

5.- Finaly, use texniccenter to compile again the .tex file.

When you need to use again sage, you don't need to write the command, because using up arrow on your keyboard will apear the command and you only have to press enter.

I think will be possible automatize 3 steps using postprocessor on texniccenter, but I don't know how to do it right now.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing! Yeah an automated solution would be great, so if you find one, please add it :)

Comment: I've tried a lot of combinations, but texniccenter help  is not clear about postprocessor use. I think using texmaker or texworks could be possible. The problem for me is that texmaker don't like spanish accents directly on the words and when I change to mac with latin1 I find a lot of problems. And using utf8 don't solve my problem. I don't know why.

Comment: Okay, that is unfortunate. You could also try the [TeXiFy plugin](https://github.com/Ruben-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA) for IntelliJ, it turns IntelliJ into a LaTeX editor with the advantage that IntelliJ is a very widely used IDE for Java and more, so it has lots of documentation, and there are tools and configurations available for postprocessing. Disclaimer: I'm a collaborator for TeXiFy.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the advice!!

Comment: Finally, I’ve found a solution for automatization. You can see it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557131/sagetex-arara-syntaxerror-unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-b?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for posting, of course arara is a great way to go about it. I will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the full instructions, adapted for Windows.

1. Find the `sagetex.sty` file of your sage installation, probably it is in `C:\Program Files\SageMath 8.0\runtime\opt\sagemath-8.0\local\share\texmf\tex\latex\sagetex\sagetex.sty`. (On for example Arch Linux, you have to install both the `sage` and `sagetex` packages, then the file will be in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/sagetex/sagetex.sty`)
2. Find out which `sagetex.sty` your computer is finding by running the TeX command `kpsewhich sagetex.sty` anywhere on your command prompt. Probably this is your MikTeX (or TeX Live or whatever distribution you are using) directory which contains an old `sagetex.sty` which is causing the version mismatch. If you get a popup asking you to install something, then don't install!
3. I'm not completely sure but I think you can just copy the new package file of your sage installation to your distribution's sagetex directory (for MikTeX something like `C:\Users\s156757\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\sagetex`) *overwriting the old sagetex.sty that is there*. If not, make sure to remove the old one and use your new file, for example by placing it next to your tex file.
4. Probably you need to install the package `fancyvrb` which sagetex needs manually using for example the MikTeX package manager.
5. Every time you add new Sage to your LaTeX: run your LaTeX file, start the Sage shell and go to the directory where the just made `myfile.sagetex.sage` was placed, which is the same directory as where all your auxiliary files are: `cd "C:/path/to/auxiliary/files"` and `sage myfile.sagetex.sage`, then run LaTeX again. Both the `.scmd` and `.sout` files are needed for for example other people to compile your LaTeX.
6. Use SageTeX with for example `$\sage{1+1}$` or with the `sageblock` environment.